# Creating a space game. Need help with a solution for creating dynamic spiral graphics

Tags: web-browser, game, game-development, web

My friend and I are working on a web based game where we want to have a blackhole-like thing rendered in some form of an engine or 3D program for us to freely manipulate adding more "arms" making it smaller or bigger and playing around with its light.

Here's a picture of our concept of the graphic element:

(smaller black hole:)
[image]

(larger black hole:)
[image]

We want help to find the best possible solution for this, and possible also some kind on guide to create these elements. So far everything is designed in photoshop but if we want the hole to be dynamic we can't use pictures.